# Shortening lengths in LaTeX

Tags: lengths, arithmetic

I'm trying to create a a bipartite object that has the `\textwidth` at most, and doesn't overflow from the right, but has the width of the separator given as an argument.

I attempted to achieve this by scaling the left side with the first optional argument and then subtracting the same amount from the right. Problem is, this doesn't compile. The error message vaguely mentions that `\relax` is expecting a number, but I don't understand why doesn't it work.

```
\newcommand{\bipart}[3][0.06]
{
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[h]{#1\textwidth} %fine
    #2
  \end{minipage}
  \vrule \hspace{0.15in}
  \begin{minipage}[h]{(0.85-#1)\textwidth} %fails
    #3
  \end{minipage}
  \vspace{0.15in}
  \normalsize
}
```

A workaround would be to add another optional argument and always do the computation myself, however I don't like that, among other things, because I would need to renumber the arguments.

Comment: Welcome! Try `\the\dimexpr0.85\textwidth-#1\textwidth` instead of `(0.85-#1)\textwidth`. (I do however not see how a default value of `3` makes sense, 0.85-3 is very negative.)

Comment: That compiled. The alignment is still wonky, but I think I can work my way from there. Why didn't the (0.85-#1) work?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, the value `[3]` is the number of arguments: two content arguments + one width which is set to 0.06 by default.

Comment: Please always post a test document not a fragment, I assume (but you don't say) that you are using `calc` package. You are inserting word spaces in several places which you are not taking account of in the calculation , after the `{` after the `\hspace` after both of the `end{minipage}`

Comment: minipage does not have a `[h]` option, the fact that it does not raise an error is just due to the memory limitations when that was implemented, it is just silently ignored

Comment: Right. I missed that. `0.06` is a reasonable default value. It does not work because (plain)  LaTeX does not parse these expressions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Thank you. I forgot the comments at the end of each line. Now everything lines up.

Comment: @AlexPetrosyan Regarding your question "Why didn't the (0.85-#1) work?": When scanning a dimension, it looks for the sequence: optional signs, then either an internal dimen register (such as `\textwidth`) or `<factor><unit of measure>`, where `<unit of measure>` itself can be either a decimal constant (like `1 pt`) or an internal dimen. Nowhere in this process TeX expects parenthesis or floating point calculations. The first one works because `#1` is the `<factor>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Naked” LaTeX doesn't understand `(0.85-#1)\textwidth` and you have to help it.

```latex
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for context

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \dimeval \dim_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\bipart}[3][0.06]{%
  \par
  \addvspace{\topsep}
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{#1\textwidth} %fine
    #2
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace{0.15in}%
  \vrule
  \hspace{0.15in}%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimeval{\fpeval{1-#1}\textwidth-0.3in-0.4pt}}
    #3
  \end{minipage}
  \par
  \addvspace{\topsep}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\bipart{a}{\lipsum[2][1-3]}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

I changed the algorithm: the vertical line has 0.15in to either side (your had a standard interword space on the left and 0.15in to the right).

The width of the other `minipage` is computed as “the complement to one of `#1` times `\textwidth` minus 0.3in (the paddings) minus 0.4pt (the rule).

I also added vertical spaces at the top and bottom, rather than just the bottom.

[image]